# Return a word position using regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble returning a word position using regex and matcher methods in java.

Let's say i have a sentence "*The quick brown fox jumps over the laziest dog in the world*" and in my current regex i want to return the position of a particular word.

Let's say the input is "brown" and from the example above, it should return 3 which is the 3rd word from the sentence. If it's "quick" it should return 2 which the 2nd word in the sentence. If it's "world" then should return 12. I hope i have given enough examples.

My try is

```
Pattern p= Pattern.compile("(?i)(?<=^|[^A-Z0-9a-z])enemy(?=$|[^A-Z0-9a-z])");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("The quickman is an enemy from megaman.");
       if(m.find()){
            System.out.println(m.start());
            System.out.println(m.end());
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
```

But the matcher.start() returns only the index of the string which is 16 and not the position of the word. Any hint or help would be appreciated.

Comment: **1.** Split the string by space, it'll return array **2.** In that array search for the word which will return index of the needle **Code:** `String haystack = "The quickman is an enemy from megaman."; String[] words = haystack.split(" "); int indexOfWorld = ArrayUtils.indexOf(haystack, "world");`

Comment: Hi @Tushar thanks for the great idea. But i'm wondering its performance for very long strings since you're storing all data split in strings in a new string array.

Comment: Above @Tushar holds the point. If you dont need to split directly what about using `indexOf()` on the string with the selected word ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example for the word `brown`:

`\b(?:(brown)|(\S+))\b`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
// \b(?:(brown)|(\S+))\b
// 
// Options: Case sensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn’t match line breaks; ^$ don’t match at line breaks; Default line breaks
// 
// Assert position at a word boundary (position preceded or followed—but not both—by a Unicode letter, digit, or underscore) «\b»
// Match the regular expression below «(?:(brown)|(\S+))»
//    Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «(brown)»
//       Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(brown)»
//          Match the character string “brown” literally (case sensitive) «brown»
//    Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «(\S+)»
//       Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(\S+)»
//          Match a single character that is NOT a “whitespace character” (ASCII space, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed) «\S+»
//             Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
// Assert position at a word boundary (position preceded or followed—but not both—by a Unicode letter, digit, or underscore) «\b»
```

Example program to find brown:

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;


public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Integer counter = new Integer(0);
    String subjectString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the laziest dog in the world";
    String testWordString = "brown";
    try {
      Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:(brown)|(\\S+))\\b");
      Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
      while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        // here increment a count for each word we pass.
        counter++;

        // matched text: regexMatcher.group()
        // match start: regexMatcher.start()
        // match end: regexMatcher.end()

        System.out.println(regexMatcher.group());

        // if the word text `regexMatcher.group()` matches our subject word `brown` exit the loop.
        if (testWordString.equals(regexMatcher.group())) {
          System.out.println("found the word: " + counter);
          break;
        }

      } 
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
      // Syntax error in the regular expression
    }
  }
}
```

This outputs:

```
The
quick
brown
found the word: 3
```

---

**Note** the example can be simplified to remove the explicit test for `brown` from:

`\b(?:(brown)|(\S+))\b`

to:

`\b(\S+)\b`

But my thought process was to allow you to use different regular expression capturing groups to indicate if you had found your match rather than using a string comparison `brown` each time again.

I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: Added additional note regarding possible simplifying of regex